# iOS stop camera feed AVCapture

Tags: ios, avcapture

I have an app, when it detects (eg CIDetect for face) it will take a picture and upload to server for processing. However during this process I want to stop the camera video feed so it does not continue to take more pictures..I tried

```
[[videoDataOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] setEnabled:NO];
```

(videoDataOutput is a AVCaptureVideoDataOutput object), but it does not seem to work...

Answer (score 1):

You send the `AVCaptureSession` object the `stopRunning` message to stop the flow of data. You can also call `removeOutput:` on the `AVCaptureSession` object to remove the individual output if you have multiple outputs and you want to keep the others active.